# jMyCarousel - cant view more than 1 instance of this carousel on one page

Tags: jquery

Hi Im a newbie so be nice;)

Im using jquery idtabs which contain 2 separate carousels in the same page (id like to up this to 4 eventually).

Unfortunately when the 2nd link is clicked the carousel does not perform as it does in link1.
You can view the example here: http://www.ipdesigned.com/bp/carousel_example.html

Im completely stumped as to why this is happening. Ive have replacated the jMyCarousel classes and called them jMyCarousel2 - Again im a newbie with this so any help y=would be greatly appreciated and also apologes if this post isnt very clear.

Cheers
Ian

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have `$(".jMyCarousel2").jMyCarousel2({ ...`, the correct function is `.jMyCarousel({...`.

Also, because you are using a class selector you only need to define the plugin once. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".jMyCarousel").jMyCarousel({
            visible: '4',
            eltByElt: true,
            evtStart: 'mousedown',
            evtStop: 'mouseup'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then change the wrapping `div` for each carousel to have the `jMyCarousel` class:

```
<div class="jMyCarousel">
```